# Expressing $\cap$ in terms of $\setminus$ and $c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If given the following identities:

$$\begin{align}
A\cap B &= (A^c\cup B^c)^c \\
A \cup B &= (A^c \cap B^c)^c \\
A\cup A^c &= X \\
A \cap A^c &= \emptyset \\
A\setminus B = A\cap B^c &=(A^c \cup B)^c
\end{align}$$

> How do I find the identity expressing $\cap$ in terms of \ and $c$?

Now my first idea is that I'm going to need to do some tricks with the statements given, but I've been working for hours and have still come up short.

Comment: You will probably want to use $(B^c)^c=B$.

Comment: @ user10354138 I've tried that

Comment: Look at the last equation.

Comment: @ user10354138  I'm looking at it, and nothing is popping out yet

Comment: @ user10354138 I don't see it. please help further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because
$$A\setminus B=A\cap B^\complement$$
Replacing $B$ with $B^\complement=X\setminus B$ we get
$$A\setminus B^\complement=A\cap (B^\complement)^\complement=A\cap B$$

Comment: thanks @Ricky. Looks so simple!

Comment: @podcastpetie remember to accept the answer and give it a thumbs up.